# How to create pivot table from a pandas dataframe having string data types in the correct order

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which looks like below,

[image]

Here is the same data in table format which you can copy/paste,

```
SourceName     SourceType   Edge       TargetName      TargetType
cardiac myosin     DISEASE  induce     myocarditis     DISEASE
cardiac myosin     DISEASE  induce     heart disease   DISEASE
nitric             CHEMICAL inhibit    chrysin         CHEMICAL
peptide magainin   CHEMICAL exhibited  tumor           DISEASE
```

Here is the same data in dictionary format which you can copy/paste,

```
{'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'SourceName': ['cardiac myosin',
  'cardiac myosin',
  'nitric',
  'peptide magainin'],
 'SourceType': ['DISEASE', 'DISEASE', 'CHEMICAL', 'CHEMICAL'],
 'Edge': ['induce', 'induce', 'inhibit', 'exhibited'],
 'TargetName': ['myocarditis',
  'heart disease',
  'chrysin',
  'tumor'],
 'TargetType': ['DISEASE', 'DISEASE', 'CHEMICAL', 'DISEASE']}
```

I tried using below code, but some of the SourceName was having wrong type, eg 'peptide magainin' should be a CHEMICAL, but it comes under DISEASE which is incorrect.

```
df1 = df.groupby(["id","SourceType","TargetType"])['SourceName', 'Edge', 'TargetName'].aggregate(lambda x: x).unstack().reset_index()
df1.columns=df1.columns.tolist()
```

Sample output which is incorrect, can someone help me with this, thanks.

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: it would help if you shared your df as text so I can copy/paste. can you edit your question with the output of `df.head(10).to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: @mitoRibo: I have edited the question and provided the data in the dictionary format, please check them, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you try to achieve with the new structure, but it can be done by grouping once by "SourceType" and once by "TargetType", then merging the resulting dataframes:

```
source_df = pd.DataFrame()
target_df = pd.DataFrame()

for s, sub_df in df.groupby('SourceType'):
    source_sub_df = sub_df[['id', 'SourceName']]
    source_sub_df.columns = ['id', f'SourceType_{s}']
    source_df = pd.concat([source_df, source_sub_df])

for t, sub_df in df.groupby('TargetType'):
    target_sub_df = sub_df[['id', 'Edge', 'TargetName']]
    target_sub_df.columns = ['id', 'Edge', f'TargetType_{t}']
    target_df = pd.concat([target_df, target_sub_df])

df_out = source_df.merge(target_df, on='id').sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   id SourceType_CHEMICAL SourceType_DISEASE       Edge TargetType_CHEMICAL TargetType_DISEASE
0   1                 NaN     cardiac myosin     induce                 NaN        myocarditis
1   2                 NaN     cardiac myosin     induce                 NaN      heart disease
2   3              nitric                NaN    inhibit             chrysin                NaN
3   4    peptide magainin                NaN  exhibited                 NaN              tumor
```

Comment: Many thanks, this worked. I will be constructing a knowledge graph with this structure, probably using Neo4j